# What is the actual meaning of ros::spin()

Tags: ros, communication, spin, topic, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know that `ros::spin` can make the subscriber and publisher run in loop to publish or receive data.

But I dont know which part in the program is running in loop or the whole program is running in loop?

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv )
{
    ros::init(argc,argv,"obstacle_finder");
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    ros::NodeHandle private_nh("~");

    ObjDet object_detector(n,private_nh);
    ros::spin();

    return 0;
}
```

Such as this example. Will the class `ObjDet` run constructor and destructor in every loop also? What is the range in the loop? Can I say all the part in `main` will run in every loop?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257361/what-is-the-actual-meaning-of-ros::spin()/) by [Bill5785](https://answers.ros.org/users/29209/bill5785/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2017-03-19

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [eRCaGuy](https://answers.ros.org/users/52105/ercaguy/) on 2020-06-17**:
This is helpful too: http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Here](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning) is a page that goes into more detail. But spin() just lets all the callbacks get called for your subscribers. Your example code doesn't have a subscriber so you wouldn't need spin() in that case.

If you did setup a subscriber and didn't have spin(), your program would just start, setup subscribers, then close without the subscriber callbacks ever getting called.

But when you do have a subscriber, all of your code runs then you put a spin() at the end to keep the program from just exiting when it reaches the end of main(). Instead of exiting, a loop continuously runs to allow the callbacks to be called when a new message arrives. To be clear, ROS will not process any callback until spin() is called.

[Here](http://answers.ros.org/question/11887/significance-of-rosspinonce/) is a related question with great answers.

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) with karma: 3460 on 2017-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 15

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bill5785](https://answers.ros.org/users/29209/bill5785/) on 2017-03-20**:
It seems that `spin` has no relationship to `publishers`, right? So how do publishers continuously publish data. (It cannot run in loop like subscribers by spin)

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2017-03-20**:
Just run a while loop and publish. Spin is not needed for publishers since there is no callback. Its mentioned in [this](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber(c2B%2B)#roscpp_tutorials.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-WritingPublisherSubscriber.The_Code) tutorial that it is good practice

**Comment by [Bill5785](https://answers.ros.org/users/29209/bill5785/) on 2017-03-20**:
The link doesnt exist. I read other tutorials and as far as I understand, `spin` and `spinOnce inside while loop` are similar except that the latter one can assign loop rate. In this case, does it mean `spin` can also make publisher run continuously if there is data to publish?

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2017-03-20**:
sorry, having trouble editing the comment, I'm working on it.

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2017-03-20**:
Geez, not sure what's going on with the link, here it is in text: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber(c%2B%2B)#roscpp_tutorials.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-WritingPublisherSubscriber.The_Code

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2017-03-20**:
Long story short, you don't need spin or spinOnce if you don't have any subscribers. Publishers don't need it because they don't use callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`ros::spin` processes messages from the callback queue. From Section 1 of the [Callback and Spinning Overview](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning):

> Implementing a spin() of our own is quite simple:

```
#include <ros/callback_queue.h>
ros::NodeHandle n;
while (ros::ok())
{
  ros::getGlobalCallbackQueue()->callAvailable(ros::WallDuration(0.1));
}
```

Briefly: the callback queue is associated with a `NodeHandle`; the `NodeHandle` is used to create your publishers and subscribers, which associates those pubs/subs with the callback queue; since you pass `private_nh` as a parameter to you `ObjDet` instance, I assume that's where your pubs/subs are created.

To your questions: no, the constructor/destructor will not be run each loop. It's not clear to me what you mean by "range in the loop". No, once `spin` is called, nothing after it is run until `ros::ok()` returns false (it's a non-returning call).

---

Originally posted by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) with karma: 1470 on 2017-03-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bill5785](https://answers.ros.org/users/29209/bill5785/) on 2017-03-20**:
"range in the loop" is the same question so ingore it. I guess there is some mistake in your last sentence. Do you want to mean once spin is called, and ros::ok is true, things after it will always run? But when ros::ok is false, things after it will stop?

**Comment by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) on 2017-03-21**:
No, I said what I meant. See if re-ordering helps: calling `spin` enters a loop that executes while `ros::ok()` is true. Once `ros::ok()` is false, the loop exits, control returns to the caller, and only then are lines after the `spin` executed.

**Comment by [here2infinity](https://answers.ros.org/users/53224/here2infinity/) on 2020-04-07**:
+1 for showing how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

"ROS Spinning, Threading, Queuing
Effective use of multi spinner threads, different queues in ROS"
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/ros-spinning-threading-queuing-aac9c0a793f

---

Edit (moderator): as this is a link only answer, here is a screenshot of the article it links to, to avoid this answer going stale in the event the site ever goes down:

[image: screenshot of article]

---

Originally posted by [cascais](https://answers.ros.org/users/39671/cascais/) with karma: 35 on 2020-08-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [breigo](https://answers.ros.org/users/35964/breigo/) on 2020-10-07**:
Finally, an illustrated, comprehensible explanation of all the queues and worker-threads. Great!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-10-08**:
As nice as the article is, link-only answers are not. They have a tendency to go stale after the linked page disappeared. I've included a screenshot of the article.

All credits to @cascais of course.